# Intermittent Azure Web App Zip Deployment failure (error status 3)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I get Intermittent deployment failures 10% of the time with azure cli (even on latest)
There is no error in the deployment logs it just says that it had a file not found exception accessing the logs!

az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group my-group --name my-app --src ./y-resource myzip-release.zip --timeout 200

WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
WARNING: Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
WARNING: Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
WARNING: Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
ERROR: Zip deployment failed. {'id': '8fdfe012-f994-4263-aea0-d3e09e34ad37', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'Push-Deployer', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2023-04-03T11:57:21.0099246Z', 'start_time': '2023-04-03T11:57:22.5833514Z', 'end_time': '2023-04-03T11:57:23.6472051Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 'url': 'https://my-url.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://my-url.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'my-app', 'build_summary': {'errors': [], 'warnings': []}}.

No trace of an error anywhere to debug with, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I tried deploying a sample Web app via zip folder with the command below and it got deployed successfully:-

In your command, Instead of using just **src** use **src-path** and ***give full path of your zip folder.***

**Command :-**

I have referred the below command from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-a-zip-package)

> ````bash
>  az webapp deploy --resource-group <resourcegroup-name> --name
> <web-app-name> --src-path "C:\dotnetapp\dotnetzipapp.zip" ```
> ````

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

***Make sure you’re using the latest version of your Azure CLI.***

**My Azure CLI version:-**

I have referred this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli#install-or-run-in-azure-cloud-shell) to check the az cli installed version

> [image]

Also, Try to ***increase your timeout period from 200 seconds to more*** as the deployment must be timing out before it gets completed:-

> ```bash
> az webapp deploy --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name
> <web-app-name> --src-path "C:\dotnetapp\dotnetzipapp.zip" --timeout
> 600
> ```
>
> As an alternative you can use Zip push deploy option from this [Link](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/10/16/Zip-Push-Deployment-for-Web-Apps,-Functions-and-WebJobs.html) Advance tool > Kudu of your App service and drag your local zip file
> directly in the zip push deploy page for deployment.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

And the zip file will be deployed in the App service, I am using Windows App Service.

> **Refer this github issue below with the same error code as yours for more insights:-**
>
> [az webapp up ZIP deployment fails · Issue #11261 · Azure/azure-cli ·
> GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11261#issuecomment-600992838)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am already using the latest version of the CLI. The problem here is that the deployment breaks intermittently after 20 seconds. The error seems to be around accessing the deployment logs like the process hasn't been released on the kudu side. I have not tried src-path but given that it works most times with src I can't see it helping.

Comment: According to the MS document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli --src-path  with full path of your zip folder is recommended, With src there might be an issue with CLI to access the entire path. Also as alternative directly dragging the Zip folder to App Service > Advance Tools > Kudu > Zip Push Deploy will make the deployment faster with the percentage and deployment logs displayed with Deployment Id.