# Install linux dependency during the python WebApp zip deployment (Azure, Oryx)

Tags: python, azure, deployment, web-applications, oryx

I would like to install linux package during the python Azure Web App (app services) deployment.

Type of the app is "code" and at the moment I cannot use docker container deployment due to non-technical restrictions.

however application requires linux library to be installed.
I am searching for the alternatives on how to deliver it without using container solutions.

One of the articles suggested to check ORYX deployment, but I cannot find any good details or demo where package dll is installed when code is deployed using zip package.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: @levgen Refer my SO answer to deploy your web app with zip deployment -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921201/intermittent-azure-web-app-zip-deployment-failure-error-status-3/75976042#

Comment: Another option to use Oryx deployment is to deploy your web app via github actions refer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588577/enable-oryx-build-being-removed-during-remote-build-and-function-app-doesnt-get/77620542#77620542

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I am searching on how to install linux library during the deployment of zip package.

Comment: @levgen > Refer this Github doc where you can utilize prebuild and post build command to install your custom linux packages with the help of oryx - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/configure-language-python.md#customize-build-automation

Comment: Another option is top dockerize your solution refer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1352581/how-to-install-linux-package-in-azure-app-service

Comment: @SiddheshDesai thank you for the reference, pre build command is not listing installing native linux libraries, that is why question appeared whether it's even works

Comment: @levgen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76735675/azure-function-do-i-have-to-use-premium-plans-custom-linux-image-feature-if-i/76778546# > Refer this SO answer  by me, See if this approach works?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [blog](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/python-setup-py-how-to-include-local-package-dependency) to install Python **`native/local`** dependencies in your Azure Web app, I have added this [Github repository](https://github.com/cj-prog/Nmspc/tree/master) mentioned in the blog in my Azure Web app and added the folder path to **`requirements.txt`** the packages from those folders- *Folder 1- ./NmspcPing , Folder 2- ./NmspcPong* got installed successfully in the Azure Web App.

***My Folder Structure:-***

[image]

My ***requirements.txt:-***

```
Django
whitenoise
./NmspcPing
./NmspcPong
```

**Output:-**

During Azure Web App deployment the local packages from **`./NmspcPing`** and **`./NmspcPong`** got deployed successfully:-

[image]

Using **`setup.py`** is also one way of installing the Linux libraries directly by *SSH'ing into Azure Web App.*

I have visited ***Azure Web App > Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go > kudu site > SSH > run the command below:-***

```py
python setup.py install
```

***Output:-***

[image]

***Azure Web app loads successfully:-***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but this also includes manual ssh step :(