# Azure Function - python and Linux Deployment issue with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a simple HTTP Trigger python V2 Azure function with one python package added for requests. The function works fine on my local machine and I can use VSCode to deploy it to Azure and it works fine over there as well. When I deploy using Azure DevOps then deployment is successful and I can see the APP_SETINGS WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE pointing to the right location on Azure storage. But when I try to run the fucntion, I get 404 not found. If I redeploy again from VS Code, everything starts working again.
[image: THe contents of the zip file]

I checked worker_venv folder and requests package is present in site-packages

Here are my build steps

[image: BUild via Azure DevOps]

I need help in figuring out how to make it work via DevOps

**Solution**
The solution from @SiddheshDesai worked. For other people facing similar issue, do not create worker_venv virtual env and install package there. Rather use pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

Comment: Is this [troubleshoot guide](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-azure-functions-http-trigger-404-error/ba-p/3766817) helpful? In addition, please download the package from the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` value for `two` deployments(pipeline and VScode), it the package content same? Please also share your deployment pipeline definition.

Comment: Thanks @wade zhou, Your suggestion was helpful. The VSCode deployment was putting dependencies under .python_packages. Azure Devops was doing it under worker_venv. Followed  the solution from SiddheshDesai and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Requests`** package is available in the **Function app** worker by default. Thus there's no need to install it separately. But if you want to install it via external dependency refer my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749362/install-linux-dependency-during-the-python-webapp-zip-deployment-azure-oryx/77925172#77925172) and add the folder path to **`requirements.txt`** like below:-

Instead of building your Web app via release pipeline, First Build your Web app via **`yaml pipeline`**, Then use the build artifact in the Release pipeline like below:-

***My Function App repository:-***

[image]

My **requirements.txt:**-

```
azure-functions
requests
./NmspcPing
./NmspcPong
```

I have added path to the external packages **`./NmspcPing`** and **`./NmspcPong`**

***Build pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx-e07e58axxxxxxx'

 
  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc769'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Release pipeline:-**

[image]

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm. For other people facing similar issue, do not create worker_venv virtual env and install package there. Rather use pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt