# Azure web app deployment failed (MacBook)

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Output:

```
1:50:53 PM macazure: Starting deployment...
1:50:53 PM macazure: Creating zip package...
1:50:54 PM macazure: Ignoring files from "appService.zipIgnorePattern"
"node_modules{,/**}"
".vscode{,/**}"
2:00:47 PM macazure: Zip package size: 294 MB
2:01:16 PM macazure: Fetching changes.
2:01:17 PM macazure: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/4b4b5d91-5076-412f-882a-17d9ca7bcd6a.zip (288.92 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:03:48 PM macazure: Updating submodules.
2:03:49 PM macazure: Preparing deployment for commit id '289201ab-2'.
2:03:49 PM macazure: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
2:03:49 PM macazure: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
2:03:49 PM macazure: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:03:50 PM macazure: Running oryx build...
2:03:50 PM macazure: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 20 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log  -i /tmp/8dc11aa4bf86edc -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log
2:03:50 PM macazure: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
2:03:50 PM macazure: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
2:03:50 PM macazure: Oryx Version: 0.2.20230829.1, Commit: 5bd3088141516cdbd815d62ada052654e91f0429, ReleaseTagName: 20230829.1
2:03:50 PM macazure: Build Operation ID: 649d0d479f627a9d
2:03:50 PM macazure: Repository Commit : 289201ab-2c04-4863-9b68-dc3d4b0c030c
2:03:50 PM macazure: OS Type           : bookworm
2:03:50 PM macazure: Image Type        : githubactions
2:03:50 PM macazure: Detecting platforms...
2:03:52 PM macazure: Error: Platform 'python' version '3.8' is unsupported. Supported versions: 
2:03:53 PM macazure: Error: Platform 'python' version '3.8' is unsupported. Supported versions:
2:03:53 PM macazure: /bin/bash -c "oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 20 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log  -i /tmp/8dc11aa4bf86edc -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log ; exit $PIPESTATUS "
2:03:53 PM macazure: Generating summary of Oryx build
2:03:53 PM macazure: Parsing the build logs
2:03:53 PM macazure: Found 0 issue(s)
2:04:13 PM macazure: Deployment failed.
```

In fact, I'm an Azure beginner. I'm trying to deploy a web app in Azure. However, the deployment is failed. My project use NodeJS Express and ReactJS.

I don't quite understand what's going on and don't know the cause of the problem.
Found 0 issue but why the deployment failed?
Is the cause is about Python? (But, my project have nothing to do with Python)

Anyways, please help me to identify the problem and it would be great if you guys provide some solution. Appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, May I know which Runtime version are you using - Refer here: https://i.imgur.com/Vda1L7b.png Hope you have selected either NODE 20 LTS or NODE 18 LTS for your web app?

Comment: Hello, I'm using NODE 20 LTS. @SiddheshDesai

Comment: Are you using this command to deploy your Web app - az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-url "https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/sample-container/myapp.zip?sv=2021-10-01&sb&sig=slk22f3UrS823n4kSh8Skjpa7Naj4CG3

Comment: I use the Azure extension in Visual Studio code to deploy.

Comment: I see looks like its an issue with the extension, You can try deploying your web app with the command above or via Github actions, As github actions also uses zip deployment. Refer my SO answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419541/how-to-solve-azure-web-app-deployment-unauthorized-code-401/76421703#76421703

Comment: Also, Refer this Document completely for Node app deployment in Azure Web app succcessfully-Enter SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT for the setting key.
nter true for the setting value. Add this setting and re-run your deployment - DOC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode

Comment: One more option is to install Azure CLI in your local system and run this command - az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path <zip-package-path> --src-path is the path to your webapp-zipped package

Answer (score 0):

Your `VS code extension` and `terminal` is causing this issue. You can use **`Github Actions`** as a work around to deploy your Express node app ***as Github Action deployment does the zip deployment by default.***

I created one sample node express app referring this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode).

**Commands:-**

```bash
npx express-generator sidexpressapp --view ejs
cd sidexpressapp
npm install
DEBUG=sidexpressapp:* npm start
```

Opened this app in Visual Studio and pushed it to Github repository:-

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first message"
git remote add origin "https://github.com/sid24desai/sidexpressapp"
git push -u origin master -f
```

***Github Repository:-***

[image]

Now, ***Created an Azure Web app with Node 20 LTS, OS: Linux*** :-

[image]

Now, ***`Visited Deployment> Deployment Center> Selected source: Github, GitHub Signed in as: sid24desai,Organization:githuborg, Repository:sidexpressapp,  Branch:main, Build provider: Github Actions,Runtime stack: Node, Version Node 20 LTS`***> Save:-

After I saved the above settings > The **Github Actions deployment** started and was successful, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Another option is to use zip **`CLI command`** to deploy your Web app like below:-

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921201/intermittent-azure-web-app-zip-deployment-failure-error-status-3/75976042#)

```bash
az login
az webapp deploy --resource-group expresssid-rg --name expresssapp --src-path "C:\Users\xxxx\sidexpressapp.zip"
```

[image]